# Docker Swarm manager cert with start date in the future: error while validating Root CA Certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Tags: docker, certificate, x509certificate, docker-swarm

I have 3 nodes that I want to play with managers and workers. My first one (Debian) I made it into a swarm manager:

```
root@debiancli:~# docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.182.129
Swarm initialized: current node (mkg6ecl3x28uyyqx7gvzz0ja3) is now a manager.

To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

    docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-47h52q7mpdkhbi4dsqyjt7pnjqgvm4oxxfh87k6e2hoj8f4op0-2p1zkg309owyophvk95bw7rj0 192.168.182.129:2377
```

To add a manager to this swarm, run 'docker swarm join-token manager' and follow the instructions.

On my second soon-to-be node (CentOS), I tried to join it to the cluster:

```
[root@centostraining ~]# docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-47h52q7mpdkhbi4dsqyjt7pnjqgvm4oxxfh87k6e2hoj8f4op0-2p1zkg309owyophvk95bw7rj0 192.168.182.129:2377
Error response from daemon: error while validating Root CA Certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

but it said, as shown above, that the certificate is not valid (date issue). I checked the date on my Debian and it is fine

```
root@debiancli:~# date
Tue Aug 14 22:02:29 EDT 2018
```

I also checked the date in my CentOS:

```
[root@centostraining ~]# date
Ter Ago 14 22:05:05 -03 2018
```

Now, I checked my swarm manager CA cert date:

```
root@debiancli:~# docker swarm ca | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep -E "Before|After" 
            Not Before: Aug 15 01:58:00 2018 GMT
            Not After : Aug 10 01:58:00 2038 GMT
```

So, weirdly enough, my certificate was generated to start the day after it was generated?
Then on my future node (CentOS), if I change the date:

```
[root@centostraining ~]# date +%Y%m%d -s "20180816"
20180816
[root@centostraining ~]# date
Qui Ago 16 00:00:01 -03 2018
[root@centostraining ~]# docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-47h52q7mpdkhbi4dsqyjt7pnjqgvm4oxxfh87k6e2hoj8f4op0-2p1zkg309owyophvk95bw7rj0 192.168.182.129:2377
This node joined a swarm as a worker.
```

Voilá, it now works as expected. Can anyone explain why my swarm ca cert is "in the future"?

Answer (score 0):

Docker's certificate is not in the future. Instead, your timezones are setup incorrectly. On one, you are showing EDT, or -4. And on the other node, it's running an hour behind since it shows the same local time but in a -3 timezone. The output from the certificate is GMT or +0.

You should be using a tool like NTP to keep your clocks in sync, which would then show the -3 machine running an hour ahead of the other in local time, but the same time if you compare the same timezone.